# Hide a child from looping movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, rendering, movieclip

I have a MovieClip that I am using several times, this MovieClip loops every 10 frames. I need to hide a child MovieClip on some but not all of these clips. When i try this, as soon as the MovieClip loops and is back on frame one, it re-appears!

This happens if I do `child.visible = false` or `parent.removeChild(child)`

I have even tried, hiding it on every frame from an EnterFrame handler, but it appears then hides on frame 2.

I understand that I could use a frame script as that code will be run before render rather than after (as with EnterFrame ) but I don't really want to do this (unless it's the only option)

edit: this child MovieClip that I am trying to hide does exist on every frame without a break too, just thought I'd mention that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there should be only one instance of the said '**child**' movieclip.

To do this,

- Add a new layer & put the movieclip into it.
- Add no more keyframes in that layer. Add blank frames only.
- Now control visibility with `.visible` or `.alpha` property.
- Do not use `parent.removeChild()` as it will remove the only instance  on stage.

Comment: the child is on its own layer and there is no keyframes or blank frames, it exists on all ten frames. I am setting child.visible = false. and it still re-appears after the first loop

Comment: if there is only one keyframe you are working with... use `stop();` at the very beginning of you code.

Comment: only one key frame for the layer containing this child, other layers have stuff going on that needs to loop over the 10 frames

Comment: Dont use removeChild. The visible & alpha property persist across loops.

Comment: I am using `visible=false`, im confused as to why it keep reapperaing as it was my understanding that it persists across loops. Hence the post

Comment: Try putting the child in a new movieclip & then control it's visible property. So that the parent would always be visible...

Comment: i need it to be inside it's parent as it isnt on top of every thing, and toi confirm i am setting the child `visible=false` and not he parent

Comment: Perhaps you should support your question with some screen shots & some more explanation.

Comment: I have a character class that has many movieclips, with animation control, and the key frame was existing on the final frame on one animation, just so happened to be the one i was testing the code on, i had correctly ordered the key frames on every aniomaton but this one, ihave now resolved, this i apologise for wasting your time and appreciate you efforts in trying to help me!!!